# Whatsapp Notification to use number of people instead of number of new messages for push icons?

Tags: iphone

Sometimes I see Whatsapp with a balloon that says 8. It might mean I have 8 new messages from persons or 3 from 1 and 5 from another.

Is it possible to configure Whatsapp on the iPhone in a way that it shows the number of people that sent me messages? 8 messages from 2 people would show a 2 in the push icon.

So that a Whatsapp icon as such would give a number based on the number of people that have sent me messages, rather than the total number of messages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not possible at the moment. Maybe you can send [them](http://www.whatsapp.com/contact/) a suggestion.